# Are causative verbs auxiliary verbs?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, causative-verbs

I can't seem to find any definitive information on this topic, as most sources simply say "these are called causative verbs" and leave it at that. To my mind, they act like auxiliary verbs in sentences such as the following:

"She **made** him do it."

"We **have** our grass cut by a landscaping company."

"His parents never **let** him do anything fun."

In all of these cases, the causative verbs seem to act *like* auxiliary verbs, meaning they "help" inform the main verbs. Or are the causatives the main verbs in these cases? How would you cut up these sentences and classify their grammatical parts in general?

Comment: No, not auxiliaries. Yes, causative verbs are all lexical; they are the matrix (your 'main') verbs in your examples.The subordinate non-finite clauses "do it", "cut by a landscaping company " and "do anything fun" are all catenative complements of the catenative verbs "made", "have" and "let". That may explain your feeling that the latter act like auxiliaries.

Comment: Yes, and that's partly where new auxiliaries like _wanna, gonna, oughta, useta, gotta,_ etc. come from -- reparsings of clauses as phrases and matrix verbs as auxiliaries. I wouldn't worry about what to call them, though -- the construction is thoroughly mixed and won't be the same in 20 or 30 years.

Comment: Two slightly different responses, but I’m grateful for both. 

I can accept these causatives as catentative verbs which function in a similar way to “ask,” as in “She asked him to dance,” or “tell,” as in “He told me to stay calm.” If I am off the mark here, please let me know. 

Sub-question, but would “him” in “She had him wash the dishes” be considered the object in this sentence, or something else? And would the dishes be the direct object in this case? Precise terminology is important to my students and me, though I realize it will never be 100% consistent.

Comment: @Alex In that sentence, "him" is the DO of "had" and "the dishes" is the DO of "wash". Some people also call "him" the subject of "wash". (I prefer to refer to emphasize their thematic relationship, with "him" as the agent.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Could you also say that “She” is the agent of “had,” just as “him” is the agent of “wash”? (“He was directed by her.” “The dishes were washed by him.”)

Comment: @Alex Yes, certainly. A subject is usually the agent of its verb when the verb is in active voice.

Comment: @Alex Yes: In "She had him wash the dishes", "him" is the syntactic object of "had" and the _understood_ (semantic) subject of "wash". Yes, in the subordinate clause "the dishes" is object of "wash".

Comment: These small verbs and the constructions they appear in are on the road to becoming new auxiliaries, but they're not there yet. When English lost her inflections, she had to make up a lot of new syntax to make up for it, and we're still doing it, and we're still changing the nature of constructions and auxiliaries.

Answer (score 1):

As BillJ commented:

> No, not auxiliaries. Yes, causative verbs are all lexical; they are the matrix (your 'main') verbs in your examples. The subordinate non-finite clauses "do it", "cut by a landscaping company " and "do anything fun" are all catenative complements of the catenative verbs "made", "have" and "let". That may explain your feeling that the latter act like auxiliaries.

Comment: Please note that H&P's CGEL treats auxiliaries as being subsumed under the category of 'catenative verbs'. So, the line @BillJ is trying to draw is at best hazy.

Comment: Please give other people's (verbatim) responses as 'community wikis'; they'll still be open to voting scrutiny.

Comment: @JK2
 CUP have [an article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/an-introduction-to-classical-nahuatl/causative-verbs/FB969FF4011DA50FA3850DD526CC0E23) by Michel Launey which, if I interpret it correctly, attests that causative verbs _are_ auxiliaries.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's interesting that the author started out by saying outright "The causative construction in English involves **an auxiliary verb of causation** taking as its direct object the person being made to act plus an infinitive of that action".